# Analyze Android Studio (Gradle) project with Sonarqube

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'am trying to analize an Android Studio project with Sonarqube.

I have the sonarqube running on my PC, the project is in a SVN repository. When I run the command `gradle sonarqube` this is the output

For all classes in the porject (src/ folder) the message is

```
Class 'abc' is not accesible through the ClassLoader
```

This is my actual configuration, the root project gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

The `app` gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

... android config
... dependencies etc ...
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.projectName', 'Material Design Sample'
        property 'sonar.working.directory', '$project.buildDir/sonar'
        property 'sonar.projectVersion', '1'
        property 'sonar.scm.provider', 'svn'
        property 'sonar.sources', 'src/main/java'
        property 'sonar.language', 'java'
        property 'sonar.sourceEncoding', 'UTF-8'
        property 'sonar.java.binaries', 'build'
        property 'sonar.java.libraries', 'libs/*.jar'
        property 'sonar.java.test.binaries', 'build'
        property 'sonar.java.test.libraries', 'libs/*.jar'
    }
}
```

I'm working with Sonar 5.5, Gradle 2.3 and Java 7, I had been reading this [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle)

I had been reading many FAQ, Q&A sites but I can't fix my problem.

Comment: Are there any news on this? I getting the same messages for all my classes and the doku didn't help. 
Could be dagger2 and/or AutoValue cause this bc of the generated classes?

Answer (score 0):

As per build script  for new, incubating, plugin mechanism introduced in Gradle 2.1:

Remove

> classpath
>   "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"

Apply sonarqube plugin to app module gradle file of your project like this

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.2.1"
}
```

After building or syncing project,open Command Prompt and navigate to app module directory where your gradle file is located.

Execute `gradle sonarqube` and wait until the build is completed.

Below is the link of post on my blog which gives complete detailed explanation of integrating sonarqube in Android with sonarqube scanner.

[Integrating and Understanding SonarQube in Android](https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/02/21/integrating-and-understanding-sonarqube-in-android/)